# 125 [баллов репутации] (/справка/что-такое-репутация)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Попробовал нажать стрелку вниз на топике. Увидел

> Благодарим за обращение. Когда вы заработаете 125 [баллов репутации]
>   (/справка/что-такое-репутация), видимый для всех рейтинг сообщений, за
>   которые вы голосовали, изменится.

Наверно тут ссылка должна быть. "Благодарим за обращение" - будто с техсапртом говорю. :)) Вобще не понял что куда изменится?

ПС. какие то сообщения на английском везде...это русский сайт или нет?

---

От редактора:

Это строки [Transifex: 6955~6957](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265015?q=Thanks%20for%20the%20feedback). Оригинальный текст:

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of $repRequired$ `[reputation](/help/whats-reputation)`, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Благодарим за обращение. Ваше сообщение о дефекте локализации очень важно для нас. Пожалуйста, дождитесь ответа модератора =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPD. Этот вариант не годится. [Странные сообщения про голосование против при голосовании в любом направлении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2107/181472)

На мой взгляд, текущий вариант (включая оригинал на английском) только запутывает неопытного читателя. Предлагаю писать прямо и понятно:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Когда ваша `[репутация](/help/whats-reputation)` достигнет  $repRequired$, вы сможете голосовать против сообщений.

Comment: Если нам позволено менять идею при локализации, то, конечно, этот вариант лучший.

Comment: @LEQADA: как бы это не привело к такому же аду, как с причинами закрытия )) Но тут вроде бы не должно.

Comment: Да не думаю, что кто-то будет против этого варианта. Он лучше, чем в оригинале.

Comment: @LEQADA: спасибо )

Comment: По-моему, в оригинале смысл совсем другой. Следует уточнить, что происходит на самом деле.

Comment: @Qwertiy: кстати, совсем недавно эти сообщения выглядели иначе: [Перевод всплывающих сообщений при попытке изменить чью-то репутацию новичком](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/379)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я где-то оригинальный английский вариант видел. Наверное, на codegolf'е.

Answer (score 4):

Этот сайт является ответвлением от сети Q&A сайтов Stack Exchange и [находится на beta-стадии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta). Идёт процесс локализации. Спасибо, что сообщили о проблеме

Предлагаю такой перевод:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Ваши голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг сообщений,
>   когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет 125.

Comment: Там речь не о влиянии, а о том, что просто можно будет голосовать против. После чего станет 124 репутации и снова станет нельзя :)

Comment: Хотя текущий текст очень сильно отличается...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я с английского перевёл. Там так же. Нет речи о минусах.

Comment: ага, добавил оригинал в вопрос. Не понимаю, зачем так сложно сказано. Тем более, в большую сторону влиять можно и раньше, этак с 15 или 20 репутации.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я ошибаюсь, или в оригинале говорится о том, что голоса принимаются и до достижения 125, а как только наберёшь репутацию 125, они все скопом применятся?

Comment: @Qwertiy, если честно, то и мне так показалось. Но не думаю, что это правда. :)

Comment: А я думаю. Это же логично в некоторой мере.

Comment: @Qwertiy, это, то есть, можно из 125 очков и не выбраться совсем? )

Comment: Хм.. А это как?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну это минусуешь всех подряд в молодости. А потом дошёл до 125 и стало 124. А потом снова 125 и снова 124. И так, пока не надоест :)

Comment: Кстати, там речь о рейтинге сообщений, а не о баллах репутации.

Comment: @Qwertiy: попробуйте зайти на любой сайт сети и там проголосовать против вопроса или ответа. Просто не получится это сделать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет Qwertiy хочет сказать, что, возможно, есть такая фича, которая собирает голоса в какую-то кучу и применяет их только тогда, когда репа достигнет 125.

Comment: @LEQADA: «голосовать против» — это отдельная привилегия. Логично, что до получения привилегии голосовать против нельзя. Кешировать голоса было бы странно и потребовало бы ненужных костылей. Подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, но в формулировке причины именно так и написано. "Когда вы наберёте n очков, ваши голоса изменят ...". Вы не чувствуете подвох? )

Comment: @LEQADA: не «изменят», а «будут менять». Никакого подвоха нет. Если прямо сразу изменят, было бы "will have changed".

Comment: Хм, а что, до 125 баллов нельзя голосовать даже за?

Comment: @VladD, в оригинале звучит именно так =\

Comment: @LEQADA: Угу, я понял. А как оно в реальности? Переспрошу в чате.