# Странные сообщения про голосование против при голосовании в любом направлении

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, голоса-против, голоса-за

Рядом с топиками стрелки, попытался на них нажимать. Когда нажимаю вверх, пишет:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Когда ваша репутация достигнет 15 баллов, вы сможете голосовать против сообщений.

когда вниз:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Когда ваша репутация достигнет 125 баллов, вы сможете голосовать против сообщений.

Баг какой-то, обе стрелки голосуют против?

Comment: Ошибка перевода, скорее всего

Comment: Как туда перенести?

Comment: @BigFan, уже перенесено)

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, ждем обновления базы строк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, это я внес эту ошибку. Повод был такой: прежняя формулировка была достаточно непонятная и я решил поменять ее на более конкретную. Чего я не учел, так это что формулировка используется как для голосования за, так и против.

Вопрос: [125 [баллов репутации] (/справка/что-такое-репутация)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1955/181472)

[Transifex: 6955~6957](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40265015?q=Thanks%20for%20the%20feedback)

Оригинал:

> Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of $repRequired$ `[reputation](/help/whats-reputation)`, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.

Прежний вариант, с битой ссылкой:

> Благодарим за обращение. Когда вы заработаете 125 `[баллов репутации] (/справка/что-такое-репутация)`, видимый для всех рейтинг сообщений, за
>   которые вы голосовали, изменится.

Исправленный вариант:

> Спасибо за отзыв! Когда ваша `[репутация](/help/whats-reputation)` достигнет  $repRequired$, вы сможете голосовать против сообщений.

---

Поскольку этот вариант явно не подходит, я временно применю [вариант от LEQADA](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1956/181472) с небольшим дополнением.

> Спасибо за отзыв! Ваши голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг сообщений, когда ваша `[репутация](/help/whats-reputation)` достигнет $repRequired$ баллов.

Можно предлагать новые варианты, если будет лидер голосования — применим его.

Answer (score 3):

Оставил комментарии в виде issue с правильным вариантом перевода в Transifex.

> Спасибо за отзыв! Когда ваша репутация достигнет 15 баллов, ваш голос будет учтен в рейтинге вопроса

Comment: Там все-таки не только вопросы, но и ответы. Я пока что применил вариант от LEQADA, но можно еще поработать над формулировкой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, про ответы не подумал, спасибо.

Comment: в общем-то поправить несложно )

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня в этом движке однако нет права менять утвержденный строки.

Comment: а я когда-то выпросил у Nicolas право на ревью.

Comment: тут еще есть такая тонкость: можно подумать, что голос пока что кешируется, а потом будет учтен. Или не подумают так?

Comment: @NickVolynkin а именно так и работает, судя по оригинальному тексту.

Comment: это нужно проверить. Особенно с голосами против это как-то странно, на них же тратится репутация.

Comment: @NickVolynkin и что? Суть-то этого сообщения в том, что голосовать ты можешь только когда наберешь определенную репутацию. И как только наберешь, твой голос будет засчитан.

Comment: "Once you earn...  " переводится как "С того момента, как вы заработаете... голоса начнут влиять на ...". И я уверен, что эти голоса нигде не кешируются, они просто не засчитываются.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "once you earn" -- "как только/когда вы заработаете". "your votes will change" -- "ваши голоса изменят", а не "начнут влиять". Тут прямое утверждение о том, что тыкания в стрелочку вверх или вниз отобразятся как только ты наберешь нужное количество репутации. И почему они не могут кэшироваться?

Comment: потому что это излишняя сложность. Голоса на закрытие и удаление ведь не кешируются впрок.